# How do I create a Json Object dynamically?

Tags: json

I want to create a Json object from the below string using Java

```
{"attributes":{"numvcpus":1,"memsize":3072},"id":"OS Node","type":"image"}
```

If I know that the string will be what it is , I can create a Json object like this

```
JsonObject jObj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
.add("attributes",Json.createObjectBuilder() 
.add("numvcpus",1) 
.add("memsize",3072))
.add("id", "OS node")
.add("type": "image").build();
```

But the problem here is I don't know how many values will come in the nested `json` object i.e, the `json` object which is the value for "attributes" field. There may be additional fields like `"disksize": 30, "lcpu": 4` etc . Is there any way to dynamically create `Json` objects, using for loop, while loop ?

Comment: What language is this in? I assume Java, but you don't specify.

Comment: I'm guessing from your question that your attributes and values are NOT hardcoded. Are they coming from an array? A more comprehensive example of what you're doing would be very useful.

Comment: To David Barker's question - I am receiving a Json response from a website, I will modify it and send the modified json back to server. So yes attributes is hardcoded but can have many key-value pairs in the json object which follows the attributes.